# How to start a self-written driver

Tags: c, windows, driver, wdf

I wrote a driver in Visual Studio 2013. The building-Process was successful.
Then I prepared a traget-computer and copied the driver-files to it.
Then I installed the driver:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pnputil -a "E:\driverZeug\KmdfHelloWorldPackage\KmdfHelloWorld.inf"
Microsoft-PnP-Dienstprogramm

Verarbeitungsinf.:            KmdfHelloWorld.inf
Das Treiberpaket wurde erfolgreich hinzugefügt.
Veröffentlichter Name:            oem42.inf


Versuche gesamt:              1
Anzahl erfolgreicher Importe: 1
```

It seems like it was successful. 
I ran DebugView on the PC but now I don't know how to start the driver, so that I can see a debug-output. I have a DbgPrintEx()-Statement in my sourcecode.

Can someone tell me how to start this driver so that I can see the output.

This is the sourcecode of the driver:

```
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <wdf.h>
DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;
EVT_WDF_DRIVER_DEVICE_ADD KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd;

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT  DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG config;

    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: DriverEntry\n");
    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: DriverEntry\n"));
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT(&config, KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd);
    status = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject, RegistryPath, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &config, WDF_NO_HANDLE);
    return status;
}

NTSTATUS KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd(_In_ WDFDRIVER Driver, _Inout_ PWDFDEVICE_INIT DeviceInit)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    WDFDEVICE hDevice;
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Driver);

    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd\n"));
    status = WdfDeviceCreate(&DeviceInit, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, &hDevice);
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to make an **EXE**(testapp) that starts your driver if installation is already done. You can use below code in the application:

```
SC_HANDLE   schService;  
SC_HANDLE   schSCManager;

schSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL,                   // local machine
                             NULL,                   // local database
                             SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS   // access required
                             ); 

// Open the handle to the existing service.
schService = OpenService(SchSCManager,
                         DriverName, //name of the driver
                         SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS
                         );

StartService(schService,     // service identifier
                  0,              // number of arguments
                  NULL            // pointer to arguments
                  ));
```

You need add code according to your need. Try this.

For more info download the samples drivers and test apps provided by microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in command line "sc" (service control) tool to start the driver.

The syntax is:

```
sc start <name>
```

So if your driver is installed with the name "KmdfHelloWorld" the command should be:

```
sc start KmdfHelloWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I am writing a GPIO Controller/Driver for Windows 8.1 & Windows 10 and have had similar issues. The easiest way to start your driver is to set up and provision a computer for driver testing and using Visual Studio to deploy, install, and start your driver on a remote machine.

It's good practice to write your driver then deploy and test remotely (either on another computer, or a VM such as VirtualBox), as this decrease your chances of messing up the computer you are writing code on.

To provision a computer, I used the following MSDN page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn745909?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

By running the prepackaged tests, you can actually have VS and Windows report on the status of the driver, get debugging info, and even set breakpoints. Trust me, for starters this is the easiest way to do this.

Also, it wouldn't hurt to register and create the callback function for the default working state, that way your driver actually does something while running. For this, use the `EVT_WDF_DEVICE_D0_ENTRY` define like you did for the `EVT_WDF_DRIVER_DEVICE_ADD`.

Happy Coding!